# Error reported on running a Mql query in tcl

Tags: tcl

Tcl support mql api.
I am running a tcl script with the below line always giving some errors.

```
set sError [catch {mql $sData} outputResult]
```

The above code is having #$Data Variable as below

```
import some data from "/home/data/filename.txt"
```

The query always works fine if we run of the mql prompt but it does not work same when ran through tcl. Some errors are always coming up showing
an issue with query. The query looks fine but I suspect in tcl that query is interpreted differently which I am not able to figure out.
Is it due to the file path or quotes that may be creating an issue. Should I be using single quote or double quote for this query so that it functions
properly in tcl context.

Comment: What error messages are produced? Does `$sData` hold _exactly_ that?

Comment: $sData is a query. which is for the mql. Error reported is missing keyword

Comment: show the exact error message, and a minimal Tcl program that reproduces the error.

Comment: single quotes have no special meaning in Tcl. See https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm